# Get the values which are created in last few minutes from a Json file

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

My Json file has the data like below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 47,
    "iid": 12,
    "project_id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "source": "push",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "ab23456789d",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/project/pipelines/47",
    "created_at": "2022-02-24T11:28:34.085Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-24T15:32:35.169Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "iid": 13,
    "project_id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "source": "web",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "ab23456789d",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/project/pipelines/48",
    "created_at": "2022-02-23T11:28:34.085Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-23T15:32:35.169Z"
  }
]
```

I am trying to fetch the IDs which are created in last 15 minutes. But I couldnt get it.

I have tried the below way,

```
TIM=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z" -d '-15 minutes'`
jq -r --arg TIMEE "$TIM" '.[]|select((.ref|contains("dev")) and (.updated_at >= "$TIMEE"))|.id' MyJsonFile.json
```

But this is not working as expected. I dont see any IDs. But when made the condition to `(.updated_at >= "$TIMEE")`. I can see all IDs which are created even in last one minute.

Not sure if I am trying in the right way. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: **What does "not working" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the time within jq, but it handles ISO 8601 dates only without milliseconds. Therefore you have to cut them off for comparison. `now` gives you the current time.

```sh
jq '.[] | select(.updated_at | "\(.[:-5])Z" | fromdate + 900 > now).id'
```

If you want to have a parameter for minutes, try:

```sh
jq --argjson min 15 '
  .[] | select(.updated_at | "\(.[:-5])Z" | fromdate + 60 * $min > now).id
'
```

Comment: Aren't the times being processed as ordinary strings? Why should the milliseconds matter?

Comment: @Barmar `fromdate` reads the dates as strings but does not like it if they contain milliseconds.

Comment: Now I see -- you're suggesting using jq's built-in date handling instead of the `date` command.

Comment: @pmf Thank you for your answer. "+1" for Immediate response

Answer (score 0):

```
TIM=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z" -d '-15 minutes'`
jq -r --arg TIMEE "$TIM" '.[]|select((.ref|contains("dev")) and (.updated_at >= $TIMEE))|.id' MyJsonFile.json
```

just removing the quote around "$TIMEE" will work. It might be taken as a string if you quote it.